# Add legend to plot and change the name of points on X axis

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a legend to my graph. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
a <- c('LSF1', 'PWD', 'GWD')

# open the pdf file
pdf(file='LSF1_PWD_GWD.pdf')

rowsToPlot<-c(93,2018,942)

matplot(as.matrix(t(tbl_alles[rowsToPlot,])),type=rep("l", length(rowsToPlot)), col=rainbow(length(rowsToPlot)),xlab = 'Fraction Size', ylab = 'Intensity', 
        legend('topright', names(a),lty=1, bty='n', cex=.75))

# close the pdf file
dev.off()
```

And the error which comes out:

`Error in as.graphicsAnnot(legend) : 
  argument "legend" is missing, with no default`

I would like to change the number of columns on X axis (from 1 to 25) for the name of the columns but keep the scale like it is.

```
colnames(tbl_alles)
 [1] "10"      "33.95"   "58.66"   "84.42"   "110.21"  "134.16"  "164.69"  "199.1"   "234.35" 
[10] "257.19"  "361.84"  "432.74"  "506.34"  "581.46"  "651.71"  "732.59"  "817.56"  "896.24" 
[19] "971.77"  "1038.91"
```

That's my data:

```
> dput(head(tbl_alles))
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `33.95` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `58.66` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.328143363, 0.552139556
), `84.42` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), `110.21` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.151581882), `134.16` = c(0.190968551, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.164736594
), `164.69` = c(0.5342874459, 0, 0.3619993464, 0, 0, 0.1891527151
), `199.1` = c(0.866134859, 0, 0.405387979, 0, 0, 0.274468991
), `234.35` = c(1, 0, 0.446118481, 0, 0, 0.338427523), `257.19` = c(0.732231652, 
0, 0.666653103, 0, 0, 0.403078017), `361.84` = c(0.660960044, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0.202578329), `432.74` = c(0.47961801, 0, 0.48323321, 
0, 0, 0.25926071), `506.34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `581.46` = c(0, 
0.52783556, 0, 1, 0, 0), `651.71` = c(0, 0.32678969, 0, 0.36428195, 
0, 0), `732.59` = c(0, 0.229023369, 0, 0.312832425, 0, 0), `817.56` = c(0, 
0.25668583, 0, 0.4003249, 0, 0), `896.24` = c(0, 0.31675535, 
0, 0.50882005, 0, 0), `971.77` = c(0, 0.27811949, 0, 0.48419038, 
0, 0), `1038.91` = c(0, 1, 0, 0.52506752, 0, 0)), .Names = c("10", 
"33.95", "58.66", "84.42", "110.21", "134.16", "164.69", "199.1", 
"234.35", "257.19", "361.84", "432.74", "506.34", "581.46", "651.71", 
"732.59", "817.56", "896.24", "971.77", "1038.91"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", 
"at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01320.2", "at1g01470.1", "at1g01800.1"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `legend(...)` should *not* be in the call to `matplot(...)`.

That is:

```
matplot(as.matrix(t(tbl_alles[rowsToPlot,])),type=rep("l", length(rowsToPlot)), col=rainbow(length(rowsToPlot)),xlab = 'Fraction Size', ylab = 'Intensity')

legend('topright', names(a),lty=1, bty='n', cex=.75)
```

Does this help?

---

EDIT:

It turns out that your legend is the content of `a` (i.e., `a` is already a vector of names - there is no need to call `names(a)` ). The right call to display the legend becomes:

```
legend('topright', a,lty=1, bty='n', cex=.75)
```

It then works on the supplied dataset.

---

EDIT 2:

To be really plain, here is what works on my computer:

```
tbl_alles = structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `33.95` = c(0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0), `58.66` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.328143363, 0.552139556
), `84.42` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), `110.21` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0.151581882), `134.16` = c(0.190968551, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.164736594
), `164.69` = c(0.5342874459, 0, 0.3619993464, 0, 0, 0.1891527151
), `199.1` = c(0.866134859, 0, 0.405387979, 0, 0, 0.274468991
), `234.35` = c(1, 0, 0.446118481, 0, 0, 0.338427523), `257.19` = c(0.732231652,
0, 0.666653103, 0, 0, 0.403078017), `361.84` = c(0.660960044,
0, 1, 0, 0, 0.202578329), `432.74` = c(0.47961801, 0, 0.48323321,
0, 0, 0.25926071), `506.34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `581.46` = c(0,
0.52783556, 0, 1, 0, 0), `651.71` = c(0, 0.32678969, 0, 0.36428195,
0, 0), `732.59` = c(0, 0.229023369, 0, 0.312832425, 0, 0), `817.56` = c(0,
0.25668583, 0, 0.4003249, 0, 0), `896.24` = c(0, 0.31675535,
0, 0.50882005, 0, 0), `971.77` = c(0, 0.27811949, 0, 0.48419038,
0, 0), `1038.91` = c(0, 1, 0, 0.52506752, 0, 0)), .Names = c("10",
"33.95", "58.66", "84.42", "110.21", "134.16", "164.69", "199.1",
"234.35", "257.19", "361.84", "432.74", "506.34", "581.46", "651.71",
"732.59", "817.56", "896.24", "971.77", "1038.91"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1",
"at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01320.2", "at1g01470.1", "at1g01800.1"
), class = "data.frame")
a <- c('LSF1', 'PWD', 'GWD')
rowsToPlot<-c(1:3)
matplot(as.matrix(t(tbl_alles[rowsToPlot,])),type=rep("l", length(rowsToPlot)), col=rainbow(length(rowsToPlot)),xlab = 'Fraction Size', ylab = 'Intensity')
legend('topright',a,lty=1, bty='n', cex=.75)
```

This gives:

[image]

It should work the same in a new R session for you :)

Comment: The error which I get now: `Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet`

Comment: This is weird. It works for my R session. Let me update my answer to provide you with a minimal working example - you can then run it in a new, clean and fresh R session and see if it works for you too.

Comment: Okey, will try to figure it out and let you know probably at the morning because it's time for me to go to bed! Thanks!

Comment: (btw, the best call to have a good legend would be `legend('topright',a, bty='n', cex=.75, lty=seq_along(a),col = seq_along(a)+1)`)